# Python module not installed in Spyder but in all other IDEs

Tags: python, spyder, pycryptodome, python-cryptography

I have pip'd pycryptodome and criptography today to use in the Spyder IDE but keep getting the error at the bottom of this page when I try to import them.

However, If I try to import them in Sublime Text or IDLE they seem to be working fine.

I am not running Spyder form Anaconda as I was having other issues there with the input() function and am just running it from my Windows platform.

I have tried uninstalling the modules as well as Spyder itself to no avail, had my uni lecturer looking at it this afternoon as well with no such luck.

Python Version 3.9.6
Spyder Version 5.3.1

Any advice?  If I need to give more info please let me know what you need and I'll try to get it.

Thanks in advance :)

### ERROR MESSAGE:

runfile('[Omitted path and filename].py', wdir='[Omitted path and filename]')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
exec(code, globals, locals)

File "[Omitted path and filename].py", line 9, in 
from Crypto.Cipher import DES

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'

Warning
It seems you're trying to use a module that doesn't come with our installer. Check this FAQ in our docs to learn how to do this.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please follow the link in the message above to understand how to fix your problem.

Comment: HI Carlos,  I followed the link but I am still a bit confused.  I do not want to be using Anaconda, I just have Spyder as a standalone IDE.  Any advice?